# Alternatives to RDD.cartesian for fuzzy join in ApacheSpark

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, fuzzy-comparison

I'm new to Spark and Scala but have the following UseCase to play around.

I've n tweets and m companies, n >> m, both in an RDD. I want to join them together in order to check which companies are present in the tweet.

In iterative programming I'd do something like a nested loop join with a custom matching function.

In Scala and Spark I'm using the cartesian function on the RDD but this gives me an out of memory exception. I've already set spark.executor.memory to 12g

Here is my code

```
val tweets = sc.textFile("/Users/romeokienzler/Documents/proj/conferences/velocity15/mytwitter/tweets.csv");
val companies = sc.textFile("/Users/romeokienzler/Documents/proj/conferences/velocity15/mytwitter/companies.csv");
val tweetsHeaderAndRows = tweets.filter(s => s.count(_ == ',')==3).map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
val tweetsHeader = tweetsHeaderAndRows.first
val tweetsData = tweetsHeaderAndRows.filter(_(0) != tweetsHeader(0))
val tweetMaps = tweetsData.map(splits => tweetsHeader.zip(splits).toMap)
val companiesData = companies.filter(s => !s.equals("COMPANY_NAME_ID"));
val tweetsWithCompany = tweetMaps.cartesian(companiesData).filter(t => t._1("TEXT").toLowerCase().contains(t._2.toLowerCase))
val companyAndScore = tweetsWithCompany.map(t => (t._2,t._1("SCORE").toDouble))
val companyFrequency = companyAndScore.map(t => (t._2,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

companyFrequency.collect()
```

And here are the two files:

https://github.com/romeokienzler/developerWorks/raw/master/tweets.csv

https://github.com/romeokienzler/developerWorks/raw/master/companies.csv

What would be a better solution to do the join?

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Is it correct that you don't want to use an equi-join? You're example looks like one.

Comment: @TillRohrmann is it part of the RDD api spec? didn't find it...

Comment: Show an example of the input data and the expected output data

Comment: In order to use the `join` operation you have to have two `RDD[Tuple2[Key, Value]]`. The first tuple entry is automatically used as the equi-join key.

Comment: This IMHO doesn't do the job because it is not a join in that sense, only tweets containing the company should be matched so in that sense the join criteria is a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

If the companies data is quite small (lets say MBs or less), you can `val companiesData = companies.collect()` to download it to the driver and then send it out as a [Broadcast Variable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables). Then you will have that variable available in any of your RDD functions on tweets that could get you something more like your iterative programming idea.

Looking at the raw data you have it seems like the companies data is very small in this example, something like ~500 company names. This should fit into a local collection just fine. Assume the starting RDDs are already munged properly:

```
val tweets: RDD[Tweet] = ...
val companies: RDD[String] = ...

val companyNames = companies.collect()
val companyNamesVar = sparkContext.broadcast(companyNames)

val companyAndScore = tweets.flatMap { tweet =>
  // parse out all the company names in this tweet
  val companyNames: Seq[String] = companyNamesVar.value.filter { name =>
    tweet("TEXT").toLowerCase.contains(name.toLowerCase)
  }

  companyNames.map(companyName => (companyName, tweet("SCORE").toDouble))
}

val companyFrequency = companyAndScore.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Comment: IMHO you are doing something similar what "cartesian" is doing, correct? And "companyNames.map(companyName => (companyName, tweet))" won't run parallelized, it will run in a single Worker, correct?

Comment: Cartesian will take every single tweet and match it up to every single company so that is m * n. The first suggestion I provided only matches company names listed on the tweet with the tweet. So if company names is 1000 entries but each tweet on average only relates to 2 companies then that is 998 entries difference per tweet. The map call isn't "parallelized" but that shouldn't matter for such a small collection. The second suggestion is very common for imbalanced joins in Spark. If you have say a hash map of your companies then you can do `map` on your tweets and do direct lookups to "join".

Comment: Looking at the raw data the company names data is very small, the broadcast variable approach is probably the best.