# Apache Spark: JOINing RDDs (data sets) using custom criteria/fuzzy matching

Tags: java, apache-spark, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison, elasticsearch-hadoop

Is it possible to join two `(Pair)RDD`s (or `Dataset`s/`DataFrame`s) (on multiple fields) using some "custom criteria"/fuzzy matching, e.g. range/interval for numbers or dates and various "distance methods", e.g. Levenshtein, for strings?

For "grouping" within an `RDD` to get a `PairRDD`, one can implement a `PairFunction`, but it seems that something similar is not possible when JOINing two `RDD`s/data sets? I am thinking something like:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2, myCustomJoinFunction);
```

I was thinking about implementing the custom logic in `hashCode()` and `equals()` but I am not sure how to make "similar" data wind up in the same bucket. I have also been looking into `RDD.cogroup()` but have not figured out how I could use it to implement this.

I just came across [elasticsearc-hadoop](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop). Does anyone know if that library could be used to do something like this?

I am using Apache Spark 2.0.0. I am implementing in Java but an answer in Scala would also be very helpful.

PS. This is my first Stackoverflow question so bear with me if I have made some newbie mistake :).

Comment: I have seen [Alternatives to RDD.cartesian for fuzzy join in ApacheSpark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376727/alternatives-to-rdd-cartesian-for-fuzzy-join-in-apachespark) but both my RDDs/data set are going to be too large to `collect()` in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DataFrames/Datasets you can use join with custom join function. Create an UDF that will be using columns from DataFrame, just like in this question [in first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132533/custom-join-with-non-equal-keys).

You can also do

```
rdd1.cartesian(rdd2).filter (...)
```

Remember that it will consume much time to calculate

Comment: Thank you! For my prototype, I am using the first answer from [custom join with non equal keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132533/custom-join-with-non-equal-keys).